# Finite State Machine trasition possibilities

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, finite-automata

Im studying finite state machines, in particular the deterministic and the non-deterministic  versions.

What i have not understood is :

why in a non-deterministic state machine it's allowed that from a state it's possible to go **nowhere** ?

This is not allewed in DSM. Why ?

Comment: It's just a matter of definition. Some people allow there to be no outgoing transitions even in DFAs. It's completely arbitrary.

Comment: If a NDSM has an equivalent in a DSM, why all the definitions that involves P,NP,ecc.. uses uses the NDSM ?

Comment: Like [Here](https://cs.joensuu.fi/pages/whamalai/daa/npsession.pdf)

Comment: The definitions of P and NP use Turing machines, not finite state machines.

Comment: Are connected comcepts ?

Comment: Perhaps it's best for you to wait until you are taught these concepts in class.

Comment: I've just studied Deterministic and not deterministic turing machines, but i still dont understand why all the definitions that involves P,NP,ecc speak about the non deterministic turining machine instead of the deterministic one ( that is the only applicable in the real world...)

Comment: Actually P is defined using deterministic Turing machines. NP can also be defined using only deterministic Turing machines (which are given access to a *witness* which they verify). See our [reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9556/what-is-the-definition-of-p-np-np-complete-and-np-hard).